# Error: Cannot match any routes, URL segment undefined

Tags: angular, parameters, angular-route-segment

I have a parent component as a list of items `TokenData` with URL segment as `locahost:4200/tokens`, when I click each row of the list, it should navigate to a child component as each item's detail. The URL segment of the child component should be in this form `tokens/:id` but the error showed up as `tokens/undefined`. Where was I wrong and how to pass each id of item in the list into the params properly?

Here is my code:

app.module.ts:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'tokens', component: TokensComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'tokens/:id', component: TokenDetailComponent }
        ]
      }
    ])
```

tokens.component.ts:

```
export class TokensComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['logo', 'token name', 'industry'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<TokenData>;

  tokens: TokenData[] = [
    { id: 'airasia', tokenName: 'Air Asia', industry: 'Airline Service' },
    { id: 'airbaltic', tokenName: 'Air Baltic', industry: 'Airline Service' },
    { id: 'airitalia', tokenName: 'Air Italia', industry: 'Airline Service' }
  ];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tokens);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for (const i of this.tokens) {
      i.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    }
  }
}
```

tokens.component.html:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>              
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [routerLink]="['/tokens/', row.id]">
    </mat-row>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="token name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> TOKEN NAME </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.tokenName}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="industry">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> INDUSTRY </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]=""> {{row.industry}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-table>
```

Comment: what is the path which you are accessing?

Comment: i accessed from `localhost:4200/tokens`, I want that when I click to a table row, e.g. Air Asia, I can move to `localhost:4200/tokens/airasia`, the params should be the id of Air Asia

Comment: path: ':id', not 'tokens/:id'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your route configurations you would need a path like `locahost:4200/tokens/tokens/25`

```
{ path: 'tokens/:id', component: TokenDetailComponent }
```

I guess what you want is

```
{ path: ':id', component: TokenDetailComponent }
```

Comment: I changed as you suggested, no more error in the console log, but the URL on browser is till `tokens/undefined`. So my function inside `ngOnInit` has problem?

Comment: I guess so. Should be easy to test if you do a `console.log(this.tokens)` at the end of `ngOnInit`

Comment: Why are you even doing this if you assign the same id to every token? You could just do `this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];` and `[routerLink]="['/tokens/', id]"` (except if you need `token.id` somewhere outside the component as well.

Comment: Oops, now all `id` in `ngOninit` is undefined. I don't understand why :(

Comment: Hard to tell from the available info. Perhaps you can create a minimal reproduction using http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Glad to hear :)